# I believe a sentence is vague/confusing and I've been told it's perfectly clear and I disagree. Why am I technically right/wrong/neither?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, compound-subjects

I claimed the sentence was confusing and unclear and was told "*No. Read it again, there's no vagueness*".

I feel like there is an explanation for *why* this is actually technically confusing/vague.

> Way back in the day **Company A** threatened to sue **Company B** for libel over claiming (rightfully) that their product was vaporware.

To me it reads, Company **A** rightfully claimed they planned to sue **Company B** for libel because Company **B** claimed that Company **A's** product was vaporware.

In reality, Company **A** threatened to sue Company **B** for libel because Company **B** rightfully claimed that Company **A's** product was vaporware.

Comment: Though the original needs TLC, your version says that **A claimed**, by removing the word *threatened*. Basically, Company A threatened to sue Company B for (libel over claiming that product of **A** was vaporware, though it was).

Comment: "The police arrested the gangsters after they robbed the bank." Who robbed the bank?

Comment: @YosefBaskin what about the use of `rightfully`? Was it rightful to sue for libel, or was it rightful to claim the product was vaporware?

Comment: @AlexKwitny Why would you expect "rightfully" to modify a verb outside the prepositional phrase rather than the verb right next to it?

Comment: The original sentence does take a little unpacking but I think it breaks out cleanly into the "in reality" version that you give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that there is formal ambiguity regarding the reference of *their*, (though I don't think it is actually ambiguous), but I think that your interpretation doesn't work, because of the word *over*, which must be governed by either *sued* or *libel*, and therefore relates to the cause of the legal action, not to the party that raised the action.

Comment: I was thinking there's ambiguity with the word `rightfully` as well? Was **A** threatening to sue rightfully over libel, or **B** rightful for claiming vaporware?

Comment: The "rightfully" clearly belongs to B's act of claiming, not to A's act of threatening.  If' A's threat was rightful then it should read "threatened (rightfully) to sue ..."